# Speeding up an insert/ignore between database server connections

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've successfully refactored the below script to select records from a table on server 1, and then connect to server 2 and insert/ignore the missing records into the cloned table there.

This works but takes about 1.5 minutes to run. I'm hoping someone can help with a slightly faster and more efficient way of doing this, since it's successful but expensive.

I don't have the option to do federated storage or replication, so this has to be done with a script. I previously did this by using the max ID of the source table but after the insert I was missing up to 15 records a day.

Here's the script:

```
$source_data = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "select * from `cdrdb`.`session` where ts >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");

while($source = $source_data->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Insert new rows into ambition.session
    $stmt = $conn2->prepare(
        "INSERT IGNORE INTO ambition.session (SESSIONID, 
         SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,
         DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE,ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING,
         CREATIONTIMESTAMP,ALERTINGTIMESTAMP,CONNECTTIMESTAMP,DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP,
         HOLDTIMESECS,LEGTYPE1,LEGTYPE2,INTERNALPARTYTYPE1,INTERNALPARTYTYPE2
         ,SERVICETYPEID1,SERVICETYPEID2,EXTENSIONID1,EXTENSIONID2,
         LOCATION1,LOCATION2,TRUNKGROUPNAME1,TRUNKGROUPNAME2,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM
         ,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO,ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1,
         SERVICEEXTENSION1,SERVICEEXTENSION2,SERVICENAME1,
         SERVICENAME2,MISSEDUSERID2,ISEMERGENCYCALL,NOTABLECALLID,
         RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID,
         ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,ACCOUNTCODE,ACCOUNTCLIENT,ORIGINATINGLEGID
         ,SYSTEMRESTARTNO,PATTERN,HOLDCOUNT,AUXSESSIONTYPE,
         DEVICEID1,DEVICEID2,ISLEG1ORIGINATING,ISLEG2ORIGINATING,
         GLOBALCALLID,CADTEMPLATEID,CADTEMPLATEID2,ts,INITIATOR,
         ACCOUNTNAME,APPNAME,CALLID,CHRTYPE,CALLERNAME,serviceid1,serviceid2)

        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    or die(mysqli_error($conn2)) ;

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,
        "iisssiissssiiiiiiiiissssiiissssiiiisssiisiiiiiiiiisisssisii"
         ,$source['SESSIONID']
         ,$source['SESSIONTYPE']
         ,$source['CALLINGPARTYNO']
         //omitting other columns for sake of space
       );
          $stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
                                    }
```

Comment: You don't need to call `prepare` every time through the loop. Prepare the statement and bind the parameters once, then use the loop to update the parameters and call `execute()`.

Comment: You probably don't need a loop at all. You can probably do this with `INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename (columns) SELECT ... FROM othertable WHERE ...`

Comment: Where is the rest of the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` call?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the columns because there are so many, And the only reason I'm not doing your previous suggestion is because the select and insert are on different database servers so they can't be in one query together

Comment: I updated with the end of my bind

Comment: You should really clean up your code to not mix OOP and Procedural, choose one and stick with it (OOP)

Comment: One other thing would be, why not run this script more often say every 5 minutes and only select 6 minutes in the past ?

Comment: I could definitely change the interval of the script and select statement, I just wanted to try and still get the process this was using to be more consice if possible. Also, where exactly is the discrepency between OOP and procedural? I was under the impression my syntax was correctly marrying the SQL and the PHP code

Comment: The mix is the use of `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` instead of `$conn->query` and `$stmt->bind_param()`. However, this is only a stylistic issue, it doesn't affect correctness or performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple improvement would be to move the call to `prepare()` to before the loop. Since the prepared statement is the same each time through the loop, there's no need to contact the DB server each time.

You can also move the call to `bind_param()` outside the loop, since the variables are the same each time. `bind_param` binds to a reference, so updating the variable will change what gets inserted when you call `execute()`.

However, these are likely to make only a small difference. One of the most effective ways to improve speed of `INSERT` queries is to insert multiple rows at a time. This is much easier to do with PDO than mysqli, because you can provide an array of parameters in the call to `$stmt->execute()`. The code would look like:

```
$params = array();
$count = 0;
$batch_size = 100;
$placeholders = implode(", ", array_fill(0, $batch_size, "(SESSIONID, 
     SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,
     DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE,ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING,
     CREATIONTIMESTAMP,ALERTINGTIMESTAMP,CONNECTTIMESTAMP,DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP,
     HOLDTIMESECS,LEGTYPE1,LEGTYPE2,INTERNALPARTYTYPE1,INTERNALPARTYTYPE2
     ,SERVICETYPEID1,SERVICETYPEID2,EXTENSIONID1,EXTENSIONID2,
     LOCATION1,LOCATION2,TRUNKGROUPNAME1,TRUNKGROUPNAME2,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM
     ,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO,ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1,
     SERVICEEXTENSION1,SERVICEEXTENSION2,SERVICENAME1,
     SERVICENAME2,MISSEDUSERID2,ISEMERGENCYCALL,NOTABLECALLID,
     RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID,
     ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,ACCOUNTCODE,ACCOUNTCLIENT,ORIGINATINGLEGID
     ,SYSTEMRESTARTNO,PATTERN,HOLDCOUNT,AUXSESSIONTYPE,
     DEVICEID1,DEVICEID2,ISLEG1ORIGINATING,ISLEG2ORIGINATING,
     GLOBALCALLID,CADTEMPLATEID,CADTEMPLATEID2,ts,INITIATOR,
     ACCOUNTNAME,APPNAME,CALLID,CHRTYPE,CALLERNAME,serviceid1,serviceid2)"));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ambition.sentence (<columns>) VALUES $placeholders");
while ($row = $source_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $params += $row; // Append this row to $params
    $count++;
    if ($count != $batch_size) {
        continue;
    }
    $stmt->execute($params);
    // Reset variables for next batch
    $params = array();
    $count = 0;
}
if ($count) { // Handle the last batch that isn't the full size
    $placeholders = implode(", ", array_fill(0, $count, "( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"));
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ambition.sentence (SESSIONID, 
         SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,
         DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE,ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING,
         CREATIONTIMESTAMP,ALERTINGTIMESTAMP,CONNECTTIMESTAMP,DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP,
         HOLDTIMESECS,LEGTYPE1,LEGTYPE2,INTERNALPARTYTYPE1,INTERNALPARTYTYPE2
         ,SERVICETYPEID1,SERVICETYPEID2,EXTENSIONID1,EXTENSIONID2,
         LOCATION1,LOCATION2,TRUNKGROUPNAME1,TRUNKGROUPNAME2,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM
         ,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO,ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1,
         SERVICEEXTENSION1,SERVICEEXTENSION2,SERVICENAME1,
         SERVICENAME2,MISSEDUSERID2,ISEMERGENCYCALL,NOTABLECALLID,
         RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID,
         ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,ACCOUNTCODE,ACCOUNTCLIENT,ORIGINATINGLEGID
         ,SYSTEMRESTARTNO,PATTERN,HOLDCOUNT,AUXSESSIONTYPE,
         DEVICEID1,DEVICEID2,ISLEG1ORIGINATING,ISLEG2ORIGINATING,
         GLOBALCALLID,CADTEMPLATEID,CADTEMPLATEID2,ts,INITIATOR,
         ACCOUNTNAME,APPNAME,CALLID,CHRTYPE,CALLERNAME,serviceid1,serviceid2) VALUES $placeholders");
    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

For this to work as I've written it, you need to ensure that the columns returned by the `SELECT` query are in the same order as the list you're inserting. Avoid using `SELECT *` when doing this, so you don't get any surprises if there's a change in the schema of the source table.

Comment: Thank you. I've inserted this to try it out and see, but I'm getting an undefined variable $pdo at the ```$stmt = $pdo->prepare``` line

Comment: It's just a variable I made up for the PDO connection returned by `new PDO`.

Comment: It's like the `$conn` variable you're using with mysqli.

Comment: I just made a correction, `$stmt->fetch()` should be `$source_data->fetch()`

Comment: Ah yes, I actually figured that so I had changed it, Thank you.

Comment: On the last $stmt->execute line it says "call to member function execute on boolean" but the first execute passed with no error?

Comment: The last `$placeholders` should use `$count` instead of `$batch_size` for the number of `VALUES` lists.

Comment: For some reason I'm just not getting it to work. I'll accept the answer and keep toying with it though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably know by now that inserting one row at a time, one transaction per row, is the slowest way to load data.

I have tested different ways of loading data, and I gave a talk at Percona Live 2017:

[Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

TL;DR: Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), even if you have to dump your source data into a CSV file first.

Here's an example, though I have not tested it:

```
$all_columns = "
  `SESSIONID`, `SESSIONTYPE`, `CALLINGPARTYNO`, `FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO`,
  `DIALPLANNAME`, `TERMINATIONREASONCODE`, `ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING`,
  `CREATIONTIMESTAMP`, `ALERTINGTIMESTAMP`, `CONNECTTIMESTAMP`,
  `DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP`, `HOLDTIMESECS`, `LEGTYPE1`, `LEGTYPE2`,
  `INTERNALPARTYTYPE1`, `INTERNALPARTYTYPE2`, `SERVICETYPEID1`, 
  `SERVICETYPEID2`, `EXTENSIONID1`, `EXTENSIONID2`, `LOCATION1`, `LOCATION2`,
  `TRUNKGROUPNAME1`, `TRUNKGROUPNAME2`, `SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM`,
  `SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO`, `ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1`, `SERVICEEXTENSION1`,
  `SERVICEEXTENSION2`, `SERVICENAME1`, `SERVICENAME2`, `MISSEDUSERID2`,
  `ISEMERGENCYCALL`, `NOTABLECALLID`, `RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID`,
  `ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO`, `ACCOUNTCODE`, `ACCOUNTCLIENT`, `ORIGINATINGLEGID`,
  `SYSTEMRESTARTNO`, `PATTERN`, `HOLDCOUNT`, `AUXSESSIONTYPE`, `DEVICEID1`,
  `DEVICEID2`, `ISLEG1ORIGINATING`, `ISLEG2ORIGINATING`, `GLOBALCALLID`,
  `CADTEMPLATEID`, `CADTEMPLATEID2`, `ts`, `INITIATOR`, `ACCOUNTNAME`, `APPNAME`,
  `CALLID`, `CHRTYPE`, `CALLERNAME`, `serviceid1`, `serviceid2`"

$select_sql = "
  SELECT $all_columns FROM `cdrdb`.`session` 
  WHERE ts >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";

$source_data = mysqli_query($conn, $select_sql);

$tmpfilename = tempnam('/tmp', 'data');
fp = fopen($tmpfilename, 'w'); // do proper error handling and use 
while ($source = $source_data->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($source));
}
fclose($fp);

$tmpfilename = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn2, $tmpfilename);

$load_sql = "
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tmpfilename' 
  IGNORE INTO TABLE `ambition`.`session`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  ( $all_columns )";

$conn2->query($load_sql);
```